# How to configure .ssh/config to use two remote repos from the same account?

Tags: git, macos, github, ssh, ssh-keys

I have two projects and for each of them I use one `github repo`. Both repos belong to one github account. I have registered the`ssh keys` of the corresponding `remote repo` in `.ssh/config`. Problem is that the `push` command works only for the repo, for one repo at a time:

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa1
```

When I try to put mutliple `ssh keys` into `config`:

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa1
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa2
```

git throws this:

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

When I do it like so, only the first key works:

```
Host github.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa1

Host github.com-repo2
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa2
```

How can I make both keys work without having to edit `config` each time I want to use the other repo?

**`Edit:`**

Trying to push with this `config` file:

```
Host github.com-repo1:me/reponame1
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_repo1

Host github.com-repo2:me/reponame2
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_repo2
```

command:

```
git push -u origin main
```

leads to the same error:

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

**`Edit2:`**

This works:

1 set url in each project to corresponding repo:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com-repo1:accountName/repo1.git
```

or

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com-repo1:accountName/repo2.git
```

2 **.ssh/config**:

```
Host github.com-repo1
  HostName github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_repo1

Host github.com-repo2
  HostName github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_repo2
```

3 push (from each project):

```
git push -u origin main
```

Comment: Are you using two deploy keys or are these two keys for the same account?  Also, can you edit your question to include the `git remote -v output` for the two repositories in question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure to include below each of your `Host` entries:

```
User git
```

Second, the remote URL for each repository would then be:

```
github.com-repo1:me/repo1
github.com-repo2:me/repo2
```

That means, for instance, that `ssh github.com-repo11` is shortcut for:

```
ssh -i  ~/.ssh/id_rsa1 git@github.com
```

---

In your case:

```
Host github.com-repo1
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_repo1
  IdentitiesOnly yes

Host github.com-repo2
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_repo2
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

The URLs would become:

```bash
cd /path/to/repo1
git remote set-url github.com-repo1:me/reponame1
git push -u origin main


cd /path/to/repo2
git remote set-url github.com-repo2:me/reponame1
git push -u origin main
```

In other words, the Host entry is just a name, not an URL.
Use that name as part of your new SSH URL.

---

The [OP Artur Müller Romanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7826511/artur-m%C3%BCller-romanov) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74155123/how-to-configure-ssh-config-to-use-two-remote-repos-from-the-same-account#comment131010845_74160564):

> I had to add the repo name (`origin`) to the `set-url` command like so:
>
> ```
> git remote set-url origin git@github.com-repo1:accountName/repo1.git.
> ```
>
> Then it worked.

Comment: I've tried adding the repo paths. Please see the edit section.

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov I have edited the answer to address your edit.

Comment: Maybe I described my problem insufficient. The remote paths for both repos (2 projects) are set correctly. But the push is not working. I have 2 projects which use one repo each and when I add two repo paths into `.ssh/config` the `push` stops working.

Comment: I've edited the question to make my problem more clear. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov Yes but my point was: `Host github.com-repo1:me/reponame1` would never work. You do not put the full URL in a `~/.ssh/config` `Host` entry. Did you try with the syntax I suggests in the answer?

Comment: yes, I've tried both. The only thing that works is `Host github.com` and only for one key.

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov What is your current remote URL in each repository? (`git remote -v` in each one of them)

Comment: Try adding `IdentitiesOnly yes` to each host block. Normally ssh tries all maybe-useful keys until one works, and lots of times that avoids having to configure anything, but it can get in the way.

Comment: @jthill Good point. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov My `~/.ssh/config` entries were missing the `Hostname` key. jthill have edited them. They should work now.

Comment: @VonC Hey, I had to add the `repo name` (origin) to the `set-url` command like so: `git remote set-url origin git@github.com-repo1:accountName/repo1.git`. Then it worked.

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov Perfect, well done. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
Host github.com-repo1
    User git
    HostName github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_repo1

Host github.com-repo2
    User git
    HostName github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_repo2
```

Try only those entries, without anything else in ~/.ssh/config

And then :

```
git clone github.com-repo1:me/reponame1
```